# JavaScript: ¿Como hago para cambiar la posicion left y top de un element obtenido por un id?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo una pagina de las tipicas de "¿Quieres ser mi novia?" y entonces aparecen 2 botones: Si y No. Quiero hacer que cuando se presione no salte a una posicion aleatoria, entonces hice esto:

HTML: Declaro los botones ():

```
<input id="yes" type="button" value="Si"><input id="no" type="button" value="No">
```

JavaScript: Obtengo los elementos por id y creo los .addEventListener para los 2, y luego coloco lo que haran:

```
let yes = document.getElementById("yes");
let no = document.getElementById("no");

yes.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    alert("Gracias, sabia que ibas a aceptar ;)");
});

no.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // Creo las variables xpos y ypos, que genera 2 numeros enteros aleatorios
    let xpos = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    let ypos = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    // Aplico las posiciones (con el "%") a las propiedades .left y .top del boton
    no.style.left = xpos+"%"; // Esto no funciona
    no.style.top  = ypos+"%"; // Eso tampoco

    /*
    Imprimi las variables xpos y ypos por la consola y funcionan, aparece un
    numero aleatorio correctamente
    */
});
```

El error esta en el .addEventListener del boton "No", no pasa absolutamente nada, ni si quiera aparece un error en la consola ¿Que es lo que esta mal?

Saludos.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar código CSS de los botones. Ten en cuenta que las propiedades `top` y `left` funcionan solo cuando se tiene posición diferente de estàtica (relativa, absoluta o fixed). Adicionalmente, creo que el evento para el botón NO, debería ser `mouseenter` para evitar que se haga clic en él.

Comment: Ahh, no lo sabia, no tengo nada en el CSS de una posicion diferente estatica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo te hace falta agregarle una posicion absoluta o relativa.

He modificado la respuesta encerrando los botones en un div y agregandole tamaño para que los botones se puedan mover, pero si le pones absolute o fixed no importa el tamaño del contenedor y se pueden mover libremente por la pantalla.

```js
let yes = document.getElementById("yes");
let no = document.getElementById("no");

yes.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  alert("Gracias, sabia que ibas a aceptar ;)");
});

no.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  alert("Ok, entendido!");
  // Creo las variables xpos y ypos, que genera 2 numeros enteros aleatorios
  let xpos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  let ypos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  // Aplico las posiciones (con el "%") a las propiedades .left y .top del boton
  no.style.position = 'relative';
  no.style.left = xpos + "%"; // Esto no funciona
  no.style.top = ypos + "%"; // Eso tampoco

  /*
  Imprimi las variables xpos y ypos por la consola y funcionan, aparece un
  numero aleatorio correctamente
  */
});
```

```css
div {display:block;height:200px;width:100%;background:green; }
```

```html
<div>
<input id="yes" type="button" value="Si">
<input id="no" type="button" value="No">
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, me acabo de dar cuenta que al menos en mi proyecto, solo cambia la x, la y nunca cambia y ademas se va siempre para la derecha

Answer (score 1):

El razonamiento está perfecto, hice esto rapidamente completo, con CSS, JS y HTML.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="contenedor">
      <h1>¿Quieres ser mi novia?</h1>
      <button id="yesBtn" type="button">Si</button>
      <button id="noBtn" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS (archivo a parte styles.css en la misma carpeta que el html):**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.contenedor {
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 165px;
  left: 230px;
}

button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 1.2rem
}

#yesBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 220px;
  left: 340px;
}

#noBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 220px;
  left: 390px;
}
```

**JavaScript (archivo app.js en la misma carpeta que los anteriores)**

```
const noBtn = document.getElementById("noBtn");
const siBtn = document.getElementById("yesBtn");

noBtn.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  const axisX = Math.round(Math.random() * 740) + "px";
  const axisY = Math.round(Math.random() * 410) + "px";
  noBtn.style.left = axisX;
  noBtn.style.top = axisY;
});

siBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert("Te quiero mucho!");
});
```

Espero te sirva, dejé todo centrado en un cuadro con un poco de estilos, al intentar presionar "No" se mueve a cualquier posición, al presionar "Si" sale un alert con un "Te quiero mucho!".